# Accessing the home screen without the capacitive home button?

Tags: broken-screen, buttons, oneplus-one, home-button

I dropped my OnePlus One, and now the bottom half of the touchscreen doesn't work. I connected a mouse to disable the lock screen, and I can now work with most apps (apart from Strava and the Camera) by rotating the screen 180 degrees (turning my phone upside down). (By the way, the phone is running a recent build of LineageOS.)

My main issue now is that I can't switch between applications. When I receive a notification, it appears at the top of the screen, and I can pull down, and touching the message opens the app. But I can't open other applications, as I can't access the home screen. The only option I know of is to reboot.

The OnePlus One has 3 capacitive (touch) buttons below its screen, and these also don't work. The middle one of these would normally bring me to the home screen. Is there another way to access the home screen other than using these 3 touch buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The 3 capacitive buttons are known as the "nav bar", and are normally off-screen on this phone. To use an on-screen version of the nav bar instead, go to Settings:

```
Settings -> System -> Buttons -> Enable on-screen nav bar
```